# EntityFramework Generic Repository, multiple include?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to change my generic retrieve method from my generic repository. But I want instead to pass a string for the includeproperties, to pass this: `params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties = null` 
The thing is when I call this method:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Retrieve(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties = null)
```

I want for example: `TEntityExample.Retrieve(filter: c=>c.Id=Id, includeProperties:c=> c.propertynav1, e=> e.propertynav1.propertynav3, e=> e.Prop4)`

Or just if dont need navigation properties `TEntityExample.Retrieve(filter: c=>c.Id=Id)`

But dont know why the `includeProperties:` is not working, is not accepted, anyone know why, or if I am doing something wrong. I want the possibility to dont pass the includeProperties or to pass it by specifying the `includeProperties:`

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Retrieve(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, string includeProperties = "")
            {
                IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;

                if (filter != null)
                {
                    query = query.Where(filter);
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(includeProperties))
                {
                    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                        (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
                    }
                }
                return query.ToList();
            }
```

Comment: What you are doing is a terrible practice! I will tell you that much. You are opening your API for everyone including you to abuse.

Comment: `includeProperties` is typed as a string and yet you are trying to send lambda expressions to it.

Comment: Yes I know I have to change the string type and also the way to include them on my query...but I want to do a compile include..if you know what I mean.

Comment: DarthVader the API is on Internet I just want to change it to my convinience...

Comment: @DarthVader I am curious how would you make various calls to get data sometimes including related entities or not? Do you add a method for every permutation or call the Load method on the entity? I am not say in your wrong I am just curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do something similar, but instead use expressions to eagerly load. Maybe this will help:

```
    public TEntity Item(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> wherePredicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        foreach (var property in includeProperties)
        {
            _dbSet.Include(property);
        }
        return _dbSet.Where(wherePredicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: You can drop the Where and just use .FirstOrDefault(wherePredicate);

Comment: Yes, I've also discovered this to be true in the 2.5 year period since this answer was originally posted.